# Linux: Tracking allocated memory over time

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to generate a graph of the allocated memory for a particular PID over time for which I am currently using a custom script that uses an `strace` log. From the `strace` log, I am aggregating the memory allocation changes from `mmap`, `munmap`, and, `brk` system calls.

I was wondering, however, if there is a better and more matured solution to do this (measure/graph the lifetime of memory allocations for a process)

Comment: I'm not aware of a more mature one, but an alternative approach - probably a more precise one - is to override `malloc(3)` & friends the way [tmalloc](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc) does.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is a tool called [massif visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer) (a part of [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)) which allows you to view graphed memory allocation for specific processes over time and is still actively maintained.